# Image2 plugin for CkEditor 4.3: how to remove URL and add border management to the properties dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm just installed a version of CkEditor 4.3, made with [CkBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder), that includes also the [Image2 plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2).

Now, I want to remove the possibility of change the URL of an image from the properties tab, opened by double-click on the image:

[image: Image Properties on CkEditor 4.3, with the Image2 Plug-in]

As you can see from the image above, I'm able to remove the "hasCaption" ckeckbox, that is present by default. To do this, I use the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image2') {        
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        infoTab.remove('hasCaption'); //Removing the "add caption" functionality
        infoTab.remove('alt'); //Removing the "alternative text" functionality
    }
});
```

My problem is that there isn't a way to remove the "change URL" functionality.

Furthermore, with the image plug-in (that is automatically disabled from CkBuilder when you add the image2 plug-in) I could change the thickness of the image border. This functionality is not provided in the new image2 plug-in.

So, my final question is the following:

**Is there a way to remove the "change URL" text field from the Image Properties tab, and add the "change border thickness" functionality?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Remove the "change URL" functionality

I found the solution to the problem about remove the "change URL" functionality. Just add the following:

```
infoTab.remove('src');
```

to the code written in the question. In this way, the complete source code is:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image2') {        
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        infoTab.remove('hasCaption'); //Removing the "add caption" functionality
        infoTab.remove('alt'); //Removing the "alternative text" functionality
        infoTab.remove('src'); //Removing the "change URL" functionality
    }
});
```

### Add the "change border thickness" functionality

From the [official Image2 plug-in page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2), in the comments section, you can find a post by [sebstefanov](http://ckeditor.com/users/sebstefanov) (probably a developer of CkEditor) in which he says that:

> [The border property] is not included because borders should be handled by the stylesheet.

After that, in the same section of the same page, some users have expressed their opposition to this choice, [sebstefanov](http://ckeditor.com/users/sebstefanov) said that the team is informed about the problem.

So the only thing I can do is to wait for some official solution...

**EDIT:** I found a solution in order to add the "change border thickness" functionality.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image2') {        
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

        infoTab.add({
            type: 'text',
            width: '50px',
            label : 'Border Thickness',
            id : 'borderField',
            'default' : '0',
            validate : function()
            {
                if ( /[^\d]/.test( this.getValue() ) )
                    return borderErrorMessage;
            }
        });

        var dialog = dialogDefinition.dialog;
        dialog.on('show', function () {
            var image = this.widget.parts.image;

            var borderField = this.getContentElement('info', 'borderField');

            //Using jQuery, I can get the border of the image.
            //You can use any other methods you prefer
            var borderWidth = $(image.$).css("border-left-width").replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
            borderWidth = borderWidth ? borderWidth : 0;

            borderField.setValue(borderWidth);
        });
        dialog.on('ok', function () {
            var image = this.widget.parts.image;

            var borderField = this.getContentElement('info', 'borderField');

            var newBorderWidth = borderField.getValue() + 'px';

            image.setStyle('border-style', 'solid');
            image.setStyle('border-width', newBorderWidth);
        });
    }

});
```

I hope this will help someone with my same problem.

Comment: Image styling should be handled by classes and external stylesheets. There will be proposed easy solution for that. But if you want a border width input, then there won't be easy solution - you'll need to add border width input to dialog and update [upcast](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast)&[downcast](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-downcast) methods of image2.

Comment: Could you provide me an example of how to do this? Or is it too complicated?